# Bhavishya purana talks about Muhammad but what does it say about allah?

Tags: shiva, bhavishya-purana, islam

I found that bhavishya purana talks about Muhammad not about allah. In quora one say that shiva will be known as allah but not sure about it.What does hinduism think about allah? I hope my hindu brothers will be hale and hearty. I love all my hindu brothers and I hope that those hindu will answer this question who also love me as a brother.
Thank you.

Comment: Bhavishya Purana only talks about the Prophet but does not say anything about Allah or about whether Shiva is Allah or not.

Comment: lets take your prayer la illahi illal la mohammed rashool allah.. i believe this statement is saying there is no god, but allah right.. we have simlary statement neti neti atma. God is not this God is not that.. God is undescribable.. like that its but even vedas unpanishad say about existence one supreme para brahman.. it can be called by any name.. Narayana, Vishnu, Narasimha. like that Allah is another if muslims brother meant one single entity which is termed God, so god can have any name, like jevoha also.. So no confusion.. in God.. God is one..

Comment: Does the specific name 'Muhammed' or 'Allah' actually occur in the Bhavishya Purana? If so where?